# Testing of interactive web app

Tags: testing, web-applications

I'm writing thesis and my supervisor told me I have to make chapter about testing but I have no idea what it should include. Can you give me some hints? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the foundations of testing, in application development, rely mainly onto a good **architecture** design.

Your application must be **modular**, structured in layers (n-tier architecture) and/or in services.

In order to test the whole application you have to test each module with some kind of **unit testing** approach. In order to do this you have to **isolate** each module and treat it as a black box.

Then your unit tests for the specific module should run against the **interface** module and all the interactions of the module towards other application components must be replaced with **mock components**, that simulates real behaviours. This is important because lets you controll what to expect in terms of successful results or failures.

After unit testing each component you can go on designing **integration tests**, that test the interactions between each module.

Then there are the **functional tests** that check that the application user experience and use cases meets the client requirements.

As a final step the appliation testing must be configured as a step of DevOps routines such as **continous integration** in order to keep your development workflow clean and secure from regressions and bugs.

Although the application testing is a HUGE argument i hope that this could help you find more informations for your thesis. Good luck!